# Wordpress: http / https hyperlink problem

Tags: php, html, wordpress

An admin input field on a website I'm working on has https://url.co.uk in it, but is outputted on the frontend as just http://url.co.uk. Any Ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Where is your code?  If you want accurate answers instead of the ridiculous guesswork that people are doing, then you need to post your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the links in the database/wp-config are still in http.

You can do 3 things:

- Force https through .htaccess : https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747758-Force-your-site-to-load-securely-with-an-htaccess-file

  - get a plugin to force https: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-ssl/
  - Replace the http links to https in the DB and force https (step 1):  https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB Use this to get it done

If this isn't the case, try to clear your cache

Comment: OP's question is not clear enough to elicit this answer. OP specifically used the word "outputted" which most likely means that it is not part of the processed page request but rather a value or setting displayed on output which may not be impacted by any specific config file.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the bellow code at your wp-config.php to avoid http/https issue :

```
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO"] ) && "https" == $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO"] ) {
$_SERVER["HTTPS"] = "on";
}
```

Comment: OP's question is not clear enough to elicit this answer.  OP specifically used the word "outputted" which most likely means that it is not part of the processed page request but rather a value or setting displayed on output which may not be impacted by any specific config file.

Comment: @JustinR. You are quite correct that question is not clearly described. But I suggest you to leave this thing to Bodman whether the answers are relevant to the question.